# How to statically check the code of a Jenkins pipeline that uses shared libraries?

Tags: jenkins, shared-libraries, jenkins-pipeline, static-analysis, lint

I'm coding [Jenkins pipelines](https://jenkins.io/doc/book/pipeline/getting-started/) but my development process is extremely inefficient. For each modification, I must commit and push my code, and manually run the pipeline. A simple typo makes me do it all again. My version control log is a mess.

I'm trying to use the [Pipeline Linter](https://jenkins.io/doc/book/pipeline/development/#linter), but it fails since it doesn't recognize the [Shared Libraries](https://jenkins.io/doc/book/pipeline/shared-libraries/) that I'm using.

Here is a simplified version of my code that I'll try to lint. This code works when I run it from the interface:

```groovy
//importing class MyClass defined in src/com/company/MyClass.groovy
import com.company.MyClass.* 
//importing src/com/company/helper/Log.groovy
import com.company.helper.Log;

def call(String env) {
    def mud

    pipeline {
        agent none

        stages{
            stage('Checkout') {
                agent any
                steps {
                        mud = new MyClass(script: this)
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I run the pipeline linter with this command:

```
 ssh -p 8222 jenkins declarative-linter < myPipeline.groovy
```

And, although it works fine when I run the pipeline in Jenkins, I get the following lint validation error:

```
Errors encountered validating Jenkinsfile:
WorkflowScript: 2: unable to resolve class com.company.helper.Log
 @ line 2, column 1.
   import com.company.helper.Log;
   ^

WorkflowScript: 25: unable to resolve class MyClass
 @ line 25, column 35.
                           mud = new MyClass(script: this)
```

How do I use the pipeline linter with shared libraries?

I also welcome any help to streamline my development process!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answer is that it isn't possible to check and Jenkins pipeline developers are doomed to have a very inefficient development process.

I've just found that there is [an issue](https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-42730) about this in Jenkins bug database. I've tried some of the solutions, but nothing worked.

I'd still like any tips about how to efficiently code Jenkins pipelines.

Comment: Add one more to the issue links which doesn't seem resolved yet - https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-59378

Answer (score 0):

I couldn't find a good solution for that  , so I created a pipeline job that contains all the relevant functions from the shared library.

once I have this flow , I can ply with it without commit anything until it works ...